# Prepare parameter for jquerys .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to load a html file to an other html-file.

For example:

```
$(function() {
    $('#main li').on('click', function() {
        var loadstring = $(this).data('url') + ' ' +  $(this).data('target');
        $('#container').load( loadstring );
    });
});

<div id="main">
    <ul>        
        <li data-url="home.html" data-target="#foo">Home</li>
        <li data-url="some.html" data-target="#bar">Some</li>                   
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="container"> </div>
```

In my `some.html` is a `<p>` element that's contains data and has the id `bar`.
In my home.html there is **no** element with the id `foo`.

**What i want to achieve is:**

I want is to check if the loaded file has elements with a specific id. *Or class, depending on passed data.* 
If yes, loadsting should look like:

```
home.html #foo
```

If not, loadsting should look like

```
home.html
```

so the whole page gets loaded.

Is there a way where I can use load() and check existing elements ?

I tried some like this

```
var loadstring = $(this).data('url') + ' ' +  $(this).data('target');
var e = $('#container').load( loadstring );
alert(e.prop('childElementCount'));
```

but this resulted 0 and on the second try it sayed that it found a element because actually its looking in my container and not in the load file :D

### For those who like to try theire luck

I just build a small 'testFiddle' ^^ **[HERE](http://dwza.de/dev/load/)**

Comment: Where is `#container` in your HTML?...

Comment: sorry, copy paste mistake. added it :D

Comment: What is $(this).data('target')? An element id? If yes, does it already containt the hash symbol?

Comment: @Markai yes, see `data-target="#foo"` and the li elements. With $(this).data('target') i select the content of the property :) in this case `#foo` or `#bar`

Comment: Ah of course, sorry. You could use a callback function for .load, in which you check if the container contains anyhing after loading `home.html #foo` and if not, just load `home.html`

Comment: load has a callback but the problem is, it loads the file into content before i can check if element exists because i actually use it on `$('#container')` so i think there must be may a other selector or some... im a lil stuck atm :)

Comment: You can create an empty, invisible element, load the element from the different file into this element, then check if it has content (within the callback). If not, load the whole page into the container, if it does, move the content from the invisible element to the container. In the end erase the invisible element

Comment: This is what I was tinking about but. But this doesnt seems to be the best way. May it's a larger file and causes lags... so this is more a fix instead a solve :D

Answer (score 0):

You'd better get the source from jquery and make your custom loader with ajax (based on https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/load.js), but it you just want to adapt your code (not tested):

```
$(function() {
    $('#main li').on('click', function() {
        var $this    = $(this);
        var url      = $(this).data('url');
        var selector = $(this).data('target');

        $('#container').load(url, function(responseText){ 
            var $content = $("<div>").append($.parseHTML(responseText)).find(selector);
            if($content.length)
               $this.html($content);
            // Else: full content already inserted by jQuery.load
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers !

Comment: Actually this is 90% of the way :D i just get a error in my console. It does what i expact it to do but i still have this error when i run the li where selector is true.

Comment: @Dwza `$content.length` here means the result of the `.find(selector)` found at least one element, regardless of their contents.

Comment: I now know :) allready corrected my comment after testing the function :)

Comment: My bad: replaced `self` with `$this` to get the jQuery environment.

Comment: Sooooo... Correct answer or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use an asynchronous call to load the file:

```
$(document).on('click', '#main li', function () {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var targetSelector = $(this).data('target');
    var callback = function (data) {
        $(targetSelector).html(data);
    };
    var dataType = 'text/html';
    $.get(url, {}, callback);
});
```

Comment: i cant really figure out how this could work in my case ?!?!? I'm trying but... i dont get any results :)

Comment: @Dwza I updated my answer to circumvent a common mistake: attempting to attach too early.

Comment: this wastn the problem I had :) I allready wrapped it in `$(document).ready(function(){...});` it simply does nothing, what ever I do. I can access it and bring url and target to console... but I dont understand the $.get at this point :)

Comment: I know what `$.get` does... :) but ... just see my example here and try your code :) http://dwza.de/dev/load/